# Spring MVC with Font-Awesome causing webfont.woff2 404 errors

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, font-awesome

I am building a Spring MVC Java application and am running into an error when trying to display a font-awesome icon.  I am getting three 404 errors when trying to display an icon.  There are some answers related to Maven which don't seem to be the cause in my case.  My 404 errors are:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/blah/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.4.0
http://127.0.0.1:8080/blah/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.4.0
http://127.0.0.1:8080/blah/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.4.0
```

Web.XML:

```
<web-app>
<display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Servlet.xml

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />

<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```

Let me know if any other info will help figure out the problem.

Update:  Here are my responses that show a bit more clearly what is going on with the requests:
[image: http responses]

Update 2:  This is how I'm referencing my local css stylesheets:
[image: stylesheets]

Also, referencing the CDN version of font-awesome allows fonts to show, but I would like to use a local copy for my application.

Comment: Where are your fonts physically located in your project? Your mvc:resources mapping is /resources/ but your URLs are /blah/fonts

Comment: Yes, the font-awesome.min.css is loading fine (200).  These calls happen after and get the 404.

Comment: does font-awesome.min.css have the same url structure?

Comment: I updated the question to show requests/responses.  The three 404 items are called by font-awesome apparently as I am not explicitly requesting these resources myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a work-around that enabled me to host my fonts locally without getting the 404 errors.  I downloaded and added directly to my project [the 3 files](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/tree/master/fonts) that were giving me the 404 errors.  Then loaded them as stylesheets:  [image: woff stylesheet]  This solved the issue, but still does not make sense why this is required.  There is still something going on with Spring I feel like as I have never had to worry about any extra files besides the main font-awesome stylesheet in the past, however this is my first Spring project.  Any other answers that don't seem so hackey I will gladly accept if they still allow for me to host the font-awesome styles locally. [image]

Answer (score 0):

You use `<default-servlet-handler />` in your servlet.xml

**default-servlet-handler**

The DefaultServletHttpRequestHandler will attempt to auto-detect the default Servlet for the container at startup time, using a list of known names for most of the major Servlet containers (including Tomcat, Jetty, GlassFish, JBoss, Resin, WebLogic, and WebSphere). If the default Servlet has been custom configured with a different name, or if a different Servlet container is being used where the default Servlet name is unknown, then the default Servlet’s name must be explicitly provided as in the following example:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable("myCustomDefaultServlet");
    }
}
```

[enter link description here](https://www.roseindia.net/spring/spring3.2/mvc-default-servlet-handler.shtml)

Update post 1 : You use default-servlet-handler and resource mapping. two elements you use together.

```
<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving 
    up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```

Update post 2 : I tried to put your stylesheet(css) in my code. With HTML5 all you need is the rel, not even the type.
[image]

Comment: I tried this and it seems to have the same effect as my <mvc:resources mapping> tag.  I can pull all my declared static resources fine, but for some reason font-awesome does these extra 3 requests to build an icon that are still failing.

Comment: I want to see your link tag (ex :  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"/ >

Comment: I tried adding using both default-servlet-handler and resource mapping with the same result.  I updated my question to show my stylesheets, also with using a CDN the icons do show, but I would like to use a local stylesheet.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help so much.  Still, the only way I can get this to work is to use the CDN, which I will not be able to do when deploying the application.  I feel like the issue is in the resource mapping somehow.  I will keep searching or put this up for bounty soon I think.